# how to make a server listen to a path in nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, socket.io

Can anyone help me figure out how to make a server in nodejs to listen to a specific path in localhost? If I replace the following path by 'port: 3000' then the localhost:3000 works properly but I just cannot find out how to carry out with path.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen({path:__dirname + '/example.html'});
app.get('/',function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/example.html');
});
```

Comment: did you read expressjs how to page?

Comment: yes i tried but the page only refers the path as a string, and it does not specify the syntax

Comment: try adding header type before sending

Comment: It seems to be very common here for people to post a question about their particular attempted solution to some problem.  But, if that's the wrong way to solve the original problem (which it is in this case), but you haven't actually described the original design problem, about all we can do is tell you that your solution is wrong and won't work, but since you haven't described your original design objective, it's hard for us to do anything more than guess what you maybe were trying to accomplish.  Please describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish (not how you're trying to do it).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by listening to `__dirname + '/example.html`?  This looks like you should be listening to a port with aw eb server and create a route to server that particular file when some particular URL is requested.

Answer (score 3):

Servers don't listen to a path (unless it's a path to a local IPC endpoint).  Here's where the [IPC path info](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_ipc_support) is documented for `.listen()`.  So a server doesn't listen to a path such as `/admin`.  For requests from the outside world, servers listen to a port and when an http request comes into that port (with any path as part of that request), they can look at the specific path requested in the http reuqest and then act accordingly.

It is possible to build or configure a proxy that will listen on a specific port and based on the path in the http request, it will then forward the request to another server on another port so that the other server will only ever receive requests starting with a particular path.  I believe that the Nginx proxy server can be configured to do that.

If you can back up and describe what you're really trying to accomplish, we can help better with a specific code or tool recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can try:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    app.listen('/tmp/sock');
```

See http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen for more details

Answer (score -1):

```js
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();
 var fs = require('fs');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get("/login", function (request, response) {
  var request= request.query.body;
    });
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: thanks gopi but I need the server to listen to a path ending /example.html, not to a port

Comment: Actually, u can do it for component not for direct html file.

Comment: U can specify a Html file path first time alone.But U can try with call back function instead of doing this.